# logback works on mac os but not on linux

Tags: java, linux, logback

I have a logback.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${app.home}/log/service.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p [%c] - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${app.home}/log/service.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>72</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="test_appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${app.home}/log/test/data.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${app.home}/log/test/data.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>72</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="file" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.test.api.TestApi" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="test_appender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.beanutils" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And I start the application with

```
nohup "$JAVACMD" -server $JAVA_OPTS \
  $EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS \
  -Dapp.name="start" \
  -Dapp.pid="$$" \
  -Dapp.repo="$REPO" \
  -Dapp.home="$BASEDIR" \
  -Dbasedir="$BASEDIR" \
  -Dev_monitoring.server.home="$BASEDIR" \
  -cp "$REPO/*" \
  com.test.server.TestServer \
  "$@" &
```

This works well in my labtop which is mac os, but is not working in linux servers, does not generate any log files in linux.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you get any error message?  Are all those shell variables set on Linux?

Comment: @codeforester No, didn't get any error messages.

Comment: @codeforester There is WARN log about "multiple SLF4J bindings" and I ignored it， that's the problem. Thank you!